# JetBrains PhpStorm red color in files don't go away

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have some files that are in red and they have absolutely no error and everything compiles properly and the web also shows properly with 0 mistakes on the console... I'm actually copy pasting the Angular tutorials; it's for sure 100% error free and still the files are red and I get so annoyed because it looks like an error...

Anyone has a solution for this???

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The red color on the tab is not because you have errors in your file. It happens because this file is new on your git repository, and yet wasn't add in work directory. You can resolve this commiting your changes.

Comment: The color can be changed in `Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | File Status`, `Unknown`

Comment: Thanks for the answer!